# Batch Edit Multiple Images

Tags: image-editing, exif

I bought a couple of digital picture frames for the grandparents for Christmas. The problem is, the picture frame displays all the pictures in landscape orientation, and half of the pictures were taken in portrait orientation. So basically, half of these pictures are being displayed sideways.

- Does the exif data control if the picture will be displayed in
  portrait or landscape mode?
- Does anyone know of software that would be able to change all the
  pictures to landscape mode? (preferably Windows or installed via Yum)
- My last resort is to try to write a script in batch, powershell, or
  bash to take care of this for me, contingent on if indeed exif
  controls the display orientation.

I tried using IfranView, but it only does file conversion or file rename via a batch job. The picture frame is a ViewSonic VFD820 and all the photos were taken on an iPhone. If there is no solution, I will write something myself (script, then a C# program eventually).

Comment: The iPhone might be an important element in this situation, I know from experience that a video taken in landspace will often still appear in portrait mode, so perhaps it's doing the same with photos... Also how many photos are you planning to 'fix'?

Comment: I have about 700 photos I'm trying to fix. I am looking at ImageMagick right now, but I don't think it is going to do what I need. The photos look fine in Windows Explorer (landscape and portrait are right side up).

Answer (score 0):

### [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/)

Picasa has a batch edit mode where you can change the view to landscape.

Go to:

**Picture > Batch Edit**

[image]

Comment: My screenshot is from an OS X version but it should be the same on the Windows version.

Comment: I've never used Picasa before, this program is pretty amazing. Thank you for your help. I thought this was what I needed to do, but I think I may need to take all these portrait photos and drop them on a black background in landscape mode.

Comment: Thanks, and welcome to AskDifferent, the way to thank someone is to upvote their answer and if you really like their answer and it worked for you, then you can also mark the answer as correct if that is what helped you with your question.